# Is it generally bad practice to have 2 different associations between the same 2 objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I realize this is somewhat opinionated, so specifically asking whether or not this is generally a good idea per code convention.

**Example scenario**

Modeling the relationship between `Books` & `Clients` in a library, where let's assume that per library rules, a client can only ever checkout one book at a time.

What's making this complex for me is the fact that a client checks a book out only for a given period of time and then returns it. So it's almost like, you don't want that relationship to continue forever... at some point, a client is relieved of the responsibilities of that book (e.g., if a book got damaged 2 years after the client had returned it, you don't want to call up a past client asking for a replacement).

Yet although it's temporal, you still want a record of the relationship, so that you can track the history of clients who have checked out a book (because down the line, maybe you do want to send a survey to past clients asking for reviews).

In other words, it seems to me like there's 2 associations... one that's temporary, and one that's more lasting.

While I can technically write the code to make this work, it seems like terrible practice (like... intuitively I feel like the answer to this question is yes... that's not good practice). But I'd like to confirm, and see if so, what are other solutions to this issue (`has_many :through` maybe with the through table having some kind of... `current_rental` attribute?)

**What 2 associations would look like**

Association #1, the temporary association, you want to know which client a book is checked out to

```
Client has_one :book, foreign_key: "current_id"
Book belongs_to :current_client, class_name: "Client", foreign_key: "current_id"
```

This relationship is very useful, if client calls and says they forgot which book they had to return from their personal book rack, you can call `@client.book.title`.

Association #2, the longer term association, you want to know the history of a book (assume further that history of a client doesn't matter, if it did this would more clearly be a `has_many :through` or HABTM relationship)

```
Client belongs_to :checkout_book, class_name: "Book", foreign_key: "book_id"
Book has_many :clients, foreign_key: "book_id"
```

This relationship allows you to look at the history of a book, how many clients it's been checked out to `@book.clients.size`, or you can email them for a survey `@book.clients.map(&:email)`.

This separation then removes the confusion where, say a book needs to be replaced, calling `@book.clients.last` may retrieve the incorrect client since reservations are made in advance and therefore checkouts don't necessarily happen in order. However, you can `@book.current_client` to get the right person to follow up with.

Comment: Consider the model is Users M-M Books. The “current book” is then simply the only book (or multiple if allowed later) that has-been-checked-our-and-not-returned. This keeps the DB model consistent without needing other trickery. A code computed property could always return a “single” book, regardless of the DB mapping. Returning a book could update a property on the joining relationship entity, or it could result in the relationship being fully deleted.

Comment: but you'd still need to have some other attribute then to determine status `checked out` in that many-to-many relationship right? I guess that's one way of looking at it. One solution is to have such an attribute, whereas my solution doesn't have an attribute but uses the relationship

Comment: Maybe in that case you could question the integrity of the relationship.  Does a client really have only one book?  The total amount of books a client can have is not what should be limited.  The total amount of books AT ONE TIME is what you want to limit.  You could set an array attribute to the name of the books the client has checked out, limiting check out limits to the length of that array.  In this case, the client could even rent out multiple books, which is very reasonable.

Comment: @james Effectively, yes (assuming the joining relationship is not temporal - in which case merely the presence indicates checked out). I like using derivable values, such as a checked in and out date. This would also allow for multiple checkout history etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason you would would want to store an extra association is to optimize read queries if you have a joined table with a huge amount of data.

Lets say that our hypothetical library is insanely popular and the are many thousands of loans per book. And we have it setup like so:

```
class Client
  has_many :loans
  has_many :books, through: :loans
end
```

```
class Book
  has_many :loans
  has_many :clients, through: :loans
end
```

```
class Loan
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :client
end
```

```
class LoansController ApplicationController
  def create
    @book = Books.find(id: params[:book_id])
    @loan = @book.loans.new(client: current_client)
    if @loan.save
      redirect_to @loan
    else
      render :new           
    end
  end
end
```

We get the requirement to list the 100 most popular books and the client that is currently in possession of the book:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def by_popularity
     @book = Book.order(popularity: :desc).limit(100)
  end
end
```

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to book.title, book %></td>
    <td><%= link_to book.clients.last.name, book.clients.last %></td> 
  <tr>
<% end %>
```

Since this causes a N+1 Query we get 101 database queries. Not good. So we throw `includes` on it to solve it.

```
@book = Book.includes(:clients)
            .order(popularity: :desc)
            .limit(100)
```

All good, right? Nope. For each of the records we are loading from books this will load and instantiate all the joined records from loans and clients. Since that's thousands and thousands the server grinds to a screeching halt as it runs out of memory.

Although there are various tricks like sub-queries to limit the output the simplest and by far most performant solution is:

```
class Book
  has_many :loans, after_add: :set_current_client
  has_many :clients, through: :loans
  belongs_to :current_client, class_name: 'Client'

  def set_current_client(client)
    update_column(current_client_id: current_client)
  end
end
```

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def by_popularity
     @book = Book.order(popularity: :desc)
                 .eager_load(:current_client)
                 .limit(100)
  end
end
```

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to book.title, book %></td>
    <td><%= link_to book.current_client.name, book.current_client %></td> 
  <tr>
<% end %>
```

### TLDR;

Is it a bad practice to have multiple associations between the two same objects? No not necessarily. It is a legitimate solution to quite a few problems but does come with some cons of its own.

Comment: in this ex, Book `belongs_to :current_client", since Rails can't guess this model based on name, you'd need to add `class: "Client", foreign_key: "current_client_id"`, right? And the counterpart on Client would be `has_one :book, foreign_key: "current_client_id"`, right? Sorry if you didn't write all that because it was already in my supposed answer and you were streamlining. I'm just double checking

Comment: Yes exactly, it was an omission on my part.